# How does model event binding work in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I got a line in the codebase that I inherited and it goes like this:

```
App.Models.Configuration   = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.bind('change', function(config, options){
      this.save_previous_state();
      // ---- 8< ---- snip
    })
  },

  // ---- 8< ---- snip
})
```

My question is, the anonymous function that gets called: `function(config, options){}` - what are the objects being passed to it, the `config` and `options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Backbone docs, at the bottom is the [catalog of events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

The Model's change event is passed the model, and a hash of options:

So, in your case, config = the changed model = itself.

Inside that event handler, you can access a few fun things like the attributes that changed:

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes

The previous state of the attributes before the change:

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previousAttributes